# dplyr::group_by - Change name of second group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'd like to group by two columns, and for the third column I'd like the value to remain same for the first group but changed to 'D5_repeat' for second group.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(rep('A',2), rep('B',2)),
                 y = c(rep('Zebra',4), rep('Lion',4)),
                 z = c(rep('D5',4), rep('D10',4)))

df %>%
  group_by(x,y) %>%
  ...
```

Results

```
#A tibble: 8 × 3
  x     y     z         
  <chr> <chr> <chr>     
1 A     Zebra D5        
2 A     Zebra D5 
3 B     Zebra D5_repeat        
4 B     Zebra D5_repeat 
5 A     Lion  D10       
6 A     Lion  D10
7 B     Lion  D10_repeat       
8 B     Lion  D10_repeat
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Can you please clarify your desired output -- is that it? What should happen to A/B Lion?

Comment: please share the desired output

Comment: Desired output is the same as df (8rows, 3 columns).  If I do group_by(x,y), there's 4 groupings right? So 1st D5, 2nd D5_repeat, 3rd D10, 4th D10_repeat.

Comment: Can you please show what the desired income would be in your question? I'm not sure I understand your description correctly.

Comment: Please, whenever someone suggests clarifications, try to edit the question so that it becomes self-contained, rather than providing the clarifications in the comments section

Comment: I'm very sorry guys. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `match(x, unique(x))` to get the group numbers of `x` in each `y` group.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  mutate(z = ifelse(match(x, unique(x)) > 1, paste0(z, '_repeat'), z)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 8 × 3
#   x     y     z
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>     
# 1 A     Zebra D5
# 2 A     Zebra D5
# 3 B     Zebra D5_repeat
# 4 B     Zebra D5_repeat
# 5 A     Lion  D10
# 6 A     Lion  D10
# 7 B     Lion  D10_repeat
# 8 B     Lion  D10_repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what're looking for?

```
df %>%
  group_by(x,y) %>%
  mutate(z = paste0(z, if_else(row_number() > 1, "_repeat", ""))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
  x     y     z         
  <chr> <chr> <chr>     
1 A     Zebra D5        
2 A     Zebra D5_repeat 
3 B     Zebra D5        
4 B     Zebra D5_repeat 
5 A     Lion  D10       
6 A     Lion  D10_repeat
7 B     Lion  D10       
8 B     Lion  D10_repeat
```